# how to create resizeable div as search engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I'am developing search engine to my App, and as part of it the user can search multiple phrase here is some example -

[image]

When the input line is full like  that:
[image]

It's height should be adjusted and the text cursor should get to the next line.

The problem is, that it's look like that in the third line my alogrithm is no longer work and it's look like that:
[image]

The structure of my the search input is like that

Html:

```
<div id=s"earchDiv">
    <input id="searchInput">
    </input>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var sDiv = document.getElementById('searchDiv');
    var sInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    var currH = $(sDiv).height();
    $(sDiv).css('height', sDiv.scrollHeight + 'px');
    var h = 40 - ($(sDiv).height() % 40);
    if ($(sDiv).height() % 40 != 0)
        $(sDiv).css('height', ($(sDiv).height() + h) + 'px');
```

which mean that acuttaly the div height is shoud be adjusted.
Someone have some idea or algorithm that can work at that situation?

Comment: Show more code regarding how you create `autocomplete` and also some more `html`

Comment: Looks like you don't need javascript at all as it can be done with CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have an error in your html:

```
<div id=s"earchDiv">
    <input id="searchInput">
    </input>
</div>
```

should be like this:

```
<div id="searchDiv">
    <input id="searchInput">
    </input>
</div>
```

after that ... i dont see why you use JS to style when you can directly use CSS to style the `searchDiv` like below:

```
.searchDiv {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; // this is important
    min-height: 40px; // change this as you wish
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via CSS.

```
#searchDiv{
     overflow:hidden; /* the parents of searchdiv should not have fixed height. */
}
```